# RegEx in R to identify how often number appears

Tags: r, regex

I want to check if a special numbers ("2020", the whole number/year) appears twice in a string. I tried this but it did not work.
Who can help me?

```
grep(pattern = "2020{2}", x = "DataMW_2029__ForecastMW_2020")
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gregexpr` to test if `2020` appears twice:

```
length(gregexpr("2020", "DataMW_2029__ForecastMW_2020")[[1]]) == 2
#[1] FALSE

length(gregexpr("2020", "DataMW_2020__ForecastMW_2020")[[1]]) == 2
#[1] TRUE
```

Or with a `regex` testing for 2 and more.

```
grepl("(.*2020){2}", "DataMW_2029__ForecastMW_2020")
#[1] FALSE

grepl("(.*2020){2}", "DataMW_2020__ForecastMW_2020")
#[1] TRUE
```

or for exact 2 hits:

```
grepl("^(?!(.*2020){3})(.*2020){2}.*$", "DataMW_2029__ForecastMW_2020", perl=TRUE)
#[1] FALSE
grepl("^(?!(.*2020){3})(.*2020){2}.*$", "DataMW_2020__ForecastMW_2020", perl=TRUE)
#[1] TRUE
grepl("^(?!(.*2020){3})(.*2020){2}.*$", "DataMW_2020__ForecastMW_2020_2020", perl=TRUE)
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `stringr::str_count()`:

```r
x <- c("DataMW_2029__ForecastMW_2020", "DataMW_2020__ForecastMW_2020")
stringr::str_count(string = x, pattern = "2020")
# [1] 1 2
stringr::str_count(string = x, pattern = "2020") == 2
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
```